# jQuery image load callback

Tags: jquery, callback, load, image

Dynamically adding an image to the page after load then user interaction and am having trouble firing a function after that image has completely loaded. I figured that using jQuery's `.load()` method would be fine.. but according my console and a bunch of documenting `.log` business it's never executed. See below.. thank you!

```
$('body')
    .append('<img id="ad" src="img/ad.jpg" alt="Advertising Network" />')
    .load(function(){
        console.log('ad load complete');
        $('#submit').click();
    });
```

---

UPDATE:

To clarify, this is after both `document` and `window` load.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your code `.load()` is related to the `body` because of chaining.

Change the code to:

```
var img = $('<img id="ad" src="img/ad.jpg" alt="Advertising Network" />');
img.load(function(){
    console.log('ad load complete');
    $('#submit').click();
});

$('body').append(img);
```

and it should work (http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/f7epb/)

Answer (score 0):

The append function returns the containing element, not the one that was appended, so you are binding your function to the body's load and not to the img.

I suggest using appendTo, like so:

```
$('<img id="ad" src="img/ad.jpg" alt="Advertising Network" />')
.load(function(){
    console.log('ad load complete');
    $('#submit').click();
})
.appendTo($('body'));
```