# How do I attach load event handlers to dynamically created images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, events, load

I am trying to attach a load event handler to images like this:

```
$(document).on('load', '.mini img', function(){
    $(this).prev().hide();
    $(this).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Can anyone explain why this isn't working?
Images are simply formed using information gotten through an ajax request and inserted using `append` method.
A lot of people had this problem and i wonder what the solution was.

Comment: You can't delegate the load event, it doesn't bubble. Show us how the images are created.

Comment: I believe that the _jQuery selector_ `.mini img` is evaluated at run-time meaning that you're not really listening for all _load_ events that hit `document`

Comment: @PaulS. You're right, but what does that have to do with the OP? They don't seem to mention wanting to know about **all** load events. And the problem is what adeneo says - that event doesn't bubble

Comment: @Ian I totally forget some events don't bubble by default

Comment: @PaulS. Me too, I only recently read it somewhere and reminded me that specifically `load` doesn't (and then adeneo's comment reminded me too). It is funny though, because I think a few events don't naturally bubble, but in jQuery event handling, it causes them to anyways

Comment: Thank you guys. Thank you and "May the force be with you" and "Live and prosper".