# Show loader GIF meanwhile a div is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I show a div on click, but the content of this div is some pretty big images and I want to add a preloader meanwhile the div is loading... I've been trying with jquery .load but can only get it to work when page first is loaded and not on click.

so i want a loader gif to be presented when aboutclick is clicked and hidden when all the content id #aboutcontent is loaded.

```
function aboutClick(){
        $('#workContent').fadeOut(400,'easeInQuint');
        $('#aboutContent').fadeIn(400,'easeInQuint');       
 };

$('#aboutContent').load(function() {
   jQuery("#gif").show(100);
});
```

Comment: If it is the image that is taking time to load, you'll have to hook load on image. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790226/jquery-image-load-callback

Comment: the thing is im using background images, and it's the entire div that takes time to load.. i don't know how to attach a .load event on a div

Comment: i've tried to do this but it doesn't work $('#aboutContent').load(function() {
   jQuery("#gif").show(100);
});

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the load event on images, it will fire as soon as the image is loaded.

```
$("#aboutContent img").load(function(){
  $("#loadergif").fadeOut(400);
});
```

This will fail, however, because if you load multiple images, your loader gif will hide as soon as the first image is loaded.

Thats why you will need to keep a counter on the amount of images, and hide it after they all finished loading.

Taken from: [jquery callback after all images in dom are loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857896/jquery-callback-after-all-images-in-dom-are-loaded)

```
$(function() {
    function imageLoaded() {
       // function to invoke for loaded image
       // decrement the counter
       counter--; 
       if( counter === 0 ) {
           // counter is 0 which means the last, so hide the loadergif
               $("#loadergif").fadeOut(400);
       }
    }
    var images = $('img');
    var counter = images.length;  // initialize the counter

    images.each(function() {
        if( this.complete ) {
            imageLoaded.call( this );
        } else {
           $(this).one('load', imageLoaded);
        }

    });
});
```

Good luck.